# Do the photon and electron fields interact even if there is no absorption?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, interference, interactions

I am talking to a friend about why light travels more slowly through glass. We came to the understanding that it is a purely quantum mechanical effect caused by the electromagnetic field inducing vibrations in the electron field which in turn creates new electromagnetic vibrations. These new vibrations then interfere with the original electromagnetic wave which produces a net effect of the overall wave being slower.

However, we're both a bit stuck understanding how the fields interact with each other if not through explicit absorption and reemission. Do the two fields continuously interact and trade energy, with absorption being a more specialized type of interaction? This seems to imply that the balance of "electron energy" to "electromagnetic energy" is always changing slightly, even if nothing is being absorbed. Is this accurate? And does it mean that all of the electromagnetic energy could theoretically be leaked into electron energy without any absorptions taking place?

Comment: *why light travels more slowly through glass* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Microscopic_explanation

Answer (score 2):

The slowing of light in a medium can be understood through classical electromagnetism. In a medium with permittivity $\epsilon$ and permeability $\mu$  light travels with speed
$$v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon \mu}} .$$
The fact that permittivity and permeability differ from their vacuum values is not a consequence of photons being quantised. Refraction can be significant even where frequencies are so low that quantum mechanical effects are not practically observable (e.g. radio wave propagation in the ionosphere).

You are correct that energy changes forms in the wave. Electrons will exchange their kinetic energy with the electric field potential energy as they are accelerated and decelerated during a cycle of the wave. This should not be thought of as absorption in a non-dissipative medium, as the changes are cyclic.

Comment: „ Electrons will exchange their kinetic energy with the electric field potential energy as they are accelerated and decelerated during a cycle of the wave.“ Shouldn't this also be applied to the passage of photons through a double slit? Interaction between the surface electrons and the photon. With consideration of phononic and other processes in the slit material.

Comment: [Do the photon and surface electron fields in the double slit interact even if there is no absorption](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/741926/do-the-photon-and-surface-electron-fields-in-the-double-slit-interact-even-if-th)